# Charts in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a requirement to create a report for different types of accounts and the balances associated with it. The report would show the group name and the summary of balances only. But i need to display charts of each account's balances when the date changes.

My report would look like this:(Sample data-here the **balance is the sum of balances till date**)

[image]

My database is something like :

[image]

Now I need 4 different charts, each one for these four account names where the y-axis would be the **balance(individual)** and x-axis would be the **transaction dates**.

Please provide your valuable inputs.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

in your `SELECT STATEMENT`

```
SELECT [Account Name],SUM(Balance) 
FROM TblName 
GROUP BY [Account Name]
```

**EDIT:**

and for creating CHARTS in CRYSTAL REPORT refer to this site [Here!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its)